# Drawing Concave Polygons Using Stencil Test

Tags: c++, opengl, polygon, stencil-buffer

I am attempting to draw concave polygons using [the stencil buffer trick outlined in the OpenGL redbook](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter14.html) but I can't seem to get it working correctly.

Per the redbook, I clear the stencil buffer first prior to enabling the stencil test. Next, I then disable any writes to the color buffer and draw my triangles. The redbook noted that I can use any arbitrary point for the start of my triangle fan call, so I used (0, 0). See the code below for reference:

```
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushAttrib( GL_CURRENT_BIT );
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glPushMatrix();
    glClear( GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT );

    glEnable( GL_STENCIL_TEST );
    glColorMask( GL_FALSE,GL_FALSE,GL_FALSE,GL_FALSE );
    glStencilOp( GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_INVERT );
    glStencilFunc( GL_ALWAYS, 0x1, 0x1 );

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);

    glVertex2d(0.0, 0.0);

    for(int i = 0; i < oglPoints.size(); i++)
    {
        glVertex2d(oglPoints[i].x, oglPoints[i].y);
    }

    glVertex2d(oglPoints[0].x, oglPoints[0].y);

    glEnd();

    glColor3d(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glColorMask( GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE );
    glStencilFunc( GL_EQUAL, 0x1, 0x1 );

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);

    for(int i = 0; i < oglPoints.size(); i++)
    {
        glVertex2d(oglPoints[i].x, oglPoints[i].y);
    }

    // glVertex2d(oglPoints[0].x, oglPoints[0].y);

    glEnd();

    glDisable( GL_STENCIL_TEST );
    glPopMatrix();
    glPopAttrib();
```

As can be seen from my attached images, I get mixed results. For some points it works, but for others it doesn't.

Correct concave polygon:

[image: Correct concave polygon]

Incorrect concave polygon 1:

[image: Incorrect concave polygon 1]

Incorrect concave polygon 2:

[image: Incorrect concave polygon 2]

Comment: Have you disabled backface culling? Why is your second pass the polygon again and not just a quad?

Comment: [This code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15285096/44729) work for you?

Comment: @NicoSchertler - Drawing a quad on the second pass just gets me, well, a quad. Am I doing something wrong with the stencil test?

Comment: @Rabbid76 - How is this not an OpenGL issue? I want to fill my polygon using the stencil test trick that was mentioned in the redbook, but I seem to have an issue getting it to work properly.

Comment: That should not happen. Do you have a stencil buffer? And have you set a reasonable stencil clear value?

Comment: @NicoSchertler - Oh man, that's it! It did not occur to me attach a stencil buffer to my framebuffer. This is great. Thank you everyone for throwing out ideas, it really helped!